# How to create an array with a passed size from a function - Lua

Tags: arrays, for-loop, lua

I have this question in my assignment

> Exercise: For loop
> Fill in each for_loop#() function to create the desired array using a for loop

```
require "testwell"

function for_loop1(len)
  local out = {}
  -- Put your code between here **************** 

  
  -- and here **********************************
 return out
end

is(for_loop1(4), {1,2,3,4}, 'For loop array creation len = 4')

is(for_loop1(9), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 'For loop array creation  len = 9')
```

i'm not sure how to pass the array length as i usually use

```
n={1,2,3...}
```

without specified size.
i tried this

```
unction for_loop1(len)
  local out = {}
  -- Put your code between here **************** 
for i= 1,4,4 do 
out ={1,2,3,4} end

for i= 1,9,9 do 
  out={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
end
  
  -- and here **********************************
 return out
end
```

but it is not working

Comment: Lua doesn't have a statement for setting array length.  Just start inserting data into empty array.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about the [numerical for loop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5). Use that to assign to each index in your table.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff i tried : out = {1,2,3,4} and got the first output right but i don't know hoe to get the other array size 9 from the same block . as you see i need to write method that receives any size and output the array accordingly.

Comment: @luther i did went through this link, but what i need is a method that takes the size of the array as an argument and output the array accordingly from the list. I'm not sure if i explained my question in a proper way ,i just started learning Lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , this worked out

```
for i = 1,len,1 do
        out[#out + 1] = i
    end
```

Comment: Hi! You can also use the table library functions http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial

`
    for i = 1, len do
        table.insert(out, i)
    end
`